# Закругление блока как на макете

Tags: html, css

Вопрос заключается в следующем. Как сделать идеальное округление блока, как на макете?
"border-bottom-left/right-radius 0px 0px" даёт немного не тот результат.
Какое еще решение можно использовать в этом вопросе?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не нужно задавать один и тот же вопрос по несколько раз.

Comment: В прошлый раз мне вполне хватило "border-bottom-left/right-radius 0px 0px". Это уже другая работа)

Comment: Не вижу никаких различий

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант сделать в графическом редакторе подходящее изображение с прозрачным фоном и сделать его фоновым изображением блока с помощью свойства BACKGROUNG-IMAGE

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
margin:0;
}

#s1 {
background: #fff;
height:50vh;
border-radius:50%;
box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
border-top-left-radius:0;
border-top-right-radius:0;
overflow:hidden;
}
#s2 {
background: #fdd;
height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<section id="s2">
<section id="s1"></section>
</section>
```

Comment: ТС в вопросе пишет, что *"border-bottom-left/right-radius 0px 0px" даёт немного не тот результат* и вы тут же предлагаете этот же вариант. Шикарно!

Comment: и что ты предлагаешь? свг?